# IIS redirect to application root

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

I need a to write a redirection in the web.config of an asp.net application, what I need is

~/Default.aspx   ->  ~/Dir1/Page1.aspx

Notice the tilde, the root changes on released version and developer version, in developer using iis express the route is /Default.aspx and in release is /somesite/Default.aspx.
How can I make this work in both cases withouth changing the web.config all the time

Comment: You really shouldn't have it change at all here. `~/` should always refer to the application root. I suspect you're deploying to a subfolder of another site instead of a subapplication.

Comment: I can't place a ~ in a redirection on system.webserver section because is an error